# Blocking a user in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web, passwords

I'm developing a website in ASP.NET where users can register and login. I want to block users for 10 mins , after they introduce the wrong password for 3 times.Is there any other solution excepting the MembershipProvider ? I tried to implement it, but it failed.
After I introduce in web.config, the code below, what else should I do ? Thanks.

```
<membership 

    defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
             type="MyMembershipProvider"
             autogenerateschema="true"
             connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             passwordFormat="Hashed"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
             passwordAttemptWindow="5"
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
             applicationName="/"  />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: which membership provider you are using

Comment: I used the MembershipProvider class from System.Web.Security  and wrote the code from above in my web.config . Could you tell me what to do from start to finish?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example for ASP.net 2.0 Membership provider, it implements a way to unlock users automatically

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Implementing-Automatic-Unlocking-in-ASP-NET-2-0-SqlMembershipProvider.id-292262.html